# phpmyadmin - unable to edit config.inc.php

Tags: php, macos, phpmyadmin

While creating a database, I added a root access password, which initially wasn't set.
And now i cant access localhost/phpmyadmin anymore

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I know I have to edit this line in the config.inc.php file

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

but I cant save the file after making the edit.
If i do it via opening the file normally, I get this:

> Failed to save 'config.inc.php': Insufficient permissions. Select
>   'Retry as Admin' to retry as administrator.

Even after clicking Retry as admin and entering the sudo password, it gives the same error.

If i try via terminal with sudo access and vim edit, I still get unable to open file for writing error.

I am on a mac. I have tried doing this via sudo from terminal, I have tried changing chmod permissions. I have browsed through almost all of the similar questions here, but none of the solution is working.
Nothing seems to work apparently.

Been stuck at this for an hour. Please help!!!

Comment: By "I can't edit the file" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @MehdiBounya I am unable to save the file after adding the password. It gives me "Failed to save 'config.inc.php': Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Admin' to retry as administrator."  although I was trying as admin. Same when I try to do it via terminal

Comment: I had the same problem and it turned out i was running a version on Mac which included a virtual machine. Try downloading one of their previous versions without the 'VM'. Found on Apachefriends support forum https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=77139&p=261282&hilit=permission+config#p261282

Answer (score 3):

Only solution I was able to find that worked successfully:

1. From the starting page of Xampp choose open terminal.
2. In case nano command is not installed, run the following command:

> sudo apt-get install nano

3. Guide to the enclosing folder of confing.inc.php with the help of cd and ls commands. In my case, the file is in

> /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin

4. Run the following command:

> sudo nano config.inc.php

5. Make the necessary changes and save the file.

Comment: what I do if not have acces to modify in xampp file ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to shuttdown the mysql service (daemon), then edit your config.inc.php and save it. in this step you can run your mysql service.

Comment: I shut down the mysql service from XAMPP. Idk what is daemon. I still can't edit the config.inc.php file. Same error
"Failed to save 'config.inc.php': Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Admin' to retry as administrator."

Comment: Ok, Daemon=Service.
I guess you're logged as an user, not an admin. you need to log to your session as an admin.

Comment: I don't think shutting the mysql service has anything to do with the file permissions...

Answer (score 0):

I used another version of `phpMyAdmin`, and I was able to edit it.

I used version: `4.9.11`.

Also make sure that the `phpMyAdmin` version is compatible with the server's `php` version:

[image: phpMyAdmin]

[phpMyAdmin download](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/)